# There is an error with the API key generated using resValue

Tags: android

I am studying various methods to hide the API key. I am trying to hide the API key in local.properties and use resValue in build.gradle:app to access it from the res file. It seems like gradleResValues.xml is generated correctly, but I cannot use the key.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Can't determine type for tag '<item name=\"api_key\" type=\"String\">wowowow</item>'","sources":[{"file":"/Users/Myapplication/app/build/generated/res/resValues/debug/values/gradleResValues.xml"}],"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}

Can't determine type for tag '<item name="api_key" type="String">wowowow</item>'
```

And there is a warning in the gradleResValues file.

```
files under the 'build' folder are generated and should not be edited
```

If I expose the same API key using buildConfigField, it works fine.
I also tried downgrading the appcompat and material library versions.

Comment: You can follow this, it's very sample: https://medium.com/@abhishekdubey331/using-gradle-to-secure-app-keys-in-android-9d2796ca4007

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest this workaround which can help you.

After adding your api key in local.properties, like this way :

```
API_KEY=123
```

You can declare in your build.gradle a new field with your api key like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField("string", "API_KEY", "\"${properties.get("API_KEY")}")
}
```

and then in your code you can access it with :

```
val apiKey = BuildConfig.API_KEY
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting on my question. However, I'm curious why resValue didn't work. As mentioned in the text, I've already tried using buildConfigField.